# How to extend a non-static class with a generic argument?

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, inner-classes

In my application, there is this line of code causing trouble:

```
public class DisplayListing<R extends Listing<R, L>, L extends Listing<R, L>.Loader> extends SherlockListFragment { ... }
```

Working with Eclipse everything behaves fine. But after switching to IntelliJ IDEA errors are popping up:

> No enclosing instance of type 'com.app.Listing' is in scope.

This error message refers to the part `Listing<R, L>.Loader` (Loader is a non-static class).

When I go to IntelliJ's preferences and change the compiler from Javac to Eclipse I'm back to business: the application will successfully compile and run again.

But the red mark indicating an error will stay (and I would like to get rid of that). So I'm wondering if I'm actually doing something wrong and my generic arguments should be fixed or if it is okay to rely on the Eclipse compiler and ignore the error?

Comment: the code looks fine in my IntelliJ. are you using java 1.7?

Comment: I just updated to 1.7 but the problem stays the same. Besides this I switched a couple times between javac and EJC and invalidated the IntelliJ cache and suddenly it successfully compiles with javac. Even though the mentioned part is still marked as error...

Comment: What's the visibility of `Loader`?

Comment: if IntelliJ behaves differently than javac, file a bug report against IntelliJ at their site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a legitimate bug, and it can be reproduced without any complex generics:

```
public class Foo<T extends Bar.Baz> {}

class Bar {
    class Baz {}
}
```

It appears that the IntelliJ parser (not its compiler, which is either `javac` or `ecj`) is mistaking the `extends Bar.Baz` to be part of the declaration of `Foo`, not `T`.  In other words, it's the same error that you (correctly) get when you do this:

```
public class Foo extends Bar.Baz {}
```

This is [IDEA Issue #94011](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94011).  You can upvote that issue to give it greater notice.

Comment: Thanks, too bad I've added an own report in between. Looks like I can't delete it...